# ファイルから行列を読み取って平均を計算できません。: TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type

Tags: python, numpy

Python を用いて以下のファイルのそれぞれの行の平均値を計算したいです。

A = 8×8の行列

そこで以下のコードを書きましたが、エラーとなってしまいます。
どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？

**コード:**

```
import numpy as np

f = open('A')
lines = f.readlines()

print (np.mean(lines, axis = 0))
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ave.py", line 6, in <module>
    print (np.mean(lines, axis = 0))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2488, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 51, in _mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Comment: `A`ファイルの実際の内容も記事に提示してください。そしてテキストファイルでしょうから、読み取っただけでは駄目で、`numpy`のデータ形式に変換する必要があるでしょう。[NumPy配列の行・列ごとの合計、平均、最大、最小などを算出](https://note.nkmk.me/python-numpy-ndarray-sum-mean-axis/)

Answer (score 1):

3x3の行列で例にすると

```
print(A)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

np.mean(A, axis=1)
array([2., 5., 8.])

np.mean(A, axis=0)
array([4., 5., 6.])
```